# Guava libraries and GWT

Tags: java, gwt, guava

Just discovered the [Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) project.

Do these work with GWT?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the introductory PDF on that page,

> You can use these libraries on...
>
> - On JDK 6
> - On Android
>     We think. Need volunteers to help us test it out.
> - On Google App Engine
>     We think. Need volunteers to help us test it out.
> - **On GWT -- spotty!
>
>     Because GWT's JDK library support is spotty
>
>     Maybe 2/3 the stuff in these libraries is GWT-safe so far 
>
>     Just look for `@GwtCompatible`! 
>
>     Performance?  Not necessarily good.**

Comment: This answer is out of date - guava in r09 now has GWT support.

Answer (score 69):

Here are some more details on how to accomplish this with the (currently latest) `19.0` release of Guava.

1. The Guava release consists of two JARs, `guava-19.0.jar` and `guava-gwt-19.0.jar`. You will need *both* for getting Guava to work within your GWT project. (In a non-GWT project you will only need the former.) Download them and add them to your project; if you use Maven, use these dependencies:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
       <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
       <version>19.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
       <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
       <version>19.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Maven will then automatically download the two Jars from the [Central Maven Repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/), see also the [Guava page on mvnrepositories](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava). As an [SBT user](http://www.scala-sbt.org), you would go for something like `libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "19.0"`.
2. Add

   ```
     <inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>
   ```

   to your GWT module file to enable Guava.

Comment: I'm having difficulty making this work in Eclipse (not using Maven). Any instructions for that?

Comment: Meanwhile, 10.0.1 is in Central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/

Comment: Thanks, xamde. I have just updated the dependencies to use version 10.0.1.

Comment: Updated to latest version (14.0.1)

Comment: Updated to latest version (18.0)/

Comment: Updated to latest version (19.0).

Comment: RC1 for 20.0 is out now.

Answer (score 20):

In the future, we'll release a working GWT module covering the @GwtCompatible subset of the library. Stay tuned.

Comment: Any idea when this might come out?

Comment: I believe we'll have it by end of September.

Comment: In maven please? I've been using guava-r06 built from the ant script. guava-r08 is in maven, but no guava-gwt.