# Using Guava in a Maven GWT Project

Tags: gwt, maven, guava

I have a project which would like to utilize the Google Guava libraries (on both the server-side and the client-side), however, I am having trouble setting it up.

I was able to add GWT and Guava as dependencies, and my GWT projects are compiling correctly.  My server-side code using Guava also works correctly.

But if I try to add it to my GWT project using the following:

```
<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect" />
```

And use the application in development mode via `mvn gwt:run`, it brings up the Google Development Mode interface and gives errors of the flavor:

```
Unable to find 'com/google/common/collect/Collect.gwt.xml' on your classpath...
```

Presumably because the maven dependency is just the compiled class files, and not the source/.gwt.xml files it needs to compile down to the Javascript.  I found that if I go to the guava website, and download the files, there is a file called guava-r08-gwt.jar, which I think is heading in the direction of a solution.

Ideally, there would be some dependency I could add in Maven that just lets me use the inherits command, but any other workarounds would be welcomed.

---

As mentioned in one of the answers, this is in the works.

In the meantime, I have set up a temporary public maven-repo for this purpose.  I make no guarantees about it staying up, but here is the repo/dependency stuff:

```
<repository>
  <id>deepthought</id>
  <name>Deepthought Public Repository</name>
  <url>http://deepthought.co/maven-repo</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
  <version>r08</version>
</dependency>
```

Feel free to use it for now, though.

Comment: Here's a similar question including answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005687/guava-libraries-and-gwt/6201161#6201161

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in the works.

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=501